# Does the FireStoreRecycler or Query make a asynchronous call to the database?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I've been fiddling around with the `Firebase Firestore` and have been using the `FireStoreUI` library to facilitate displaying data from my database in my RecyclerView.

However, I noticed that by using the `Query` object and it's `orderBy` function, I am able to only display a single value from my Array that's inside the database.

I then proceeded to add:

```
@Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       Log.e("TITLE","result" + super.getItemCount());
       return super.getItemCount();
   }
```

In my `FirestoreAdapter` class. For a few seconds, I get a result of 0, and then I get a result of 1. As in the screenshot:

[image: Result]

And here's my Firestore Database:

[image: Database]

Which makes me wonder, is this why my `RecyclerView` only displays the first value of the array?
Do I have to create some sort of `callBack` function? Because most documentation/tutorials I've seen about it don't have one.

Here's my `Activity`

```
public class OsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirestoreAdapter listAdapter;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference osRef = db.collection("cliente");
    private DocumentReference docRef = osRef.document("clienteTeste");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_os);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOs);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        /*docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    Log.e("RESULTADO","result:" + document.toString());
                }
            }
        });*/

        Query query = osRef.orderBy("serviceOrder",
                Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceDocument> options =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ServiceDocument>()
                        .setQuery(query, ServiceDocument.class)
                        .build();

         listAdapter = new FirestoreAdapter(options);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        listAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        listAdapter.stopListening();
    }
```

And here's my `Adapter`:

```
public class FirestoreAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ServiceDocument, FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public FirestoreAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ServiceDocument> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ServiceDocument model) {
        holder.osIdItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.serviceOrder.get(position).getId()));
        holder.osClientItem.setText(model.serviceOrder.get(position).getClient().getName());
        holder.osDateItem.setText(model.serviceOrder.get(position).getDate());
        holder.osValueItem.setText(String.valueOf(model.serviceOrder.get(position).getTotalValue()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_os_item, parent, false);

        return new FirestoreAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("TITLE","result" + super.getItemCount());
        return super.getItemCount();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private  TextView osIdItem;
        private  TextView osClientItem;
        private  TextView osDateItem;
        private  TextView osValueItem;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            osIdItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osIDItem);
            osClientItem =   itemView.findViewById(R.id.osClientNameItem);
            osDateItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osDateItem);
            osValueItem =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.osValueItem);
        }
    }
}
```

**The commented part of my `Activity` shows me that I am getting both fields from my database, as an array, so I don't know why my RecyclerView doesn't.**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but: yes, data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously. If that doesn't answer your question, can you point out exactly what line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I'm not sure it is a line of code. I expected my `Recycler` to display both of the values in my database, as shown in the image. However, it only loads the first field `0` . Why doesn't it also show the value at position `1`  ? I can post a screenshot of my Recycler if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` creates one child view in the `RecyclerView` for each document. Since you have only a single document under `cliente`, it is the expected behavior that only a single child shows up in the recycler view.

If you need a different behavior, you'll probably want to create your own adapter. The Android documentation on [creating dynamic lists with RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview) contains a step-by-step guide for this.

Comment: So it is impossible to display all the positions of an array  in a `RecyclerView` by using the default `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter`? I assume I'll have to put all the `document` data in an `ArrayList` and use that as an adapter for the custom adapter?

Comment: The `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` creates one item for each document. Since you have only a single document under `cliente`, you get a single child item in the recycler view. The documentation I linked uses a `private String[] localDataSet` to store the data that it wants to show, so yeah, you can use an `ArrayList` too.